# Auto refresh div going next line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple code with jquery and slim framework and here it is:

jquery:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#counter').load('/requests/autoloader').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

`/requests/autoloader` route

```
$stat = 1;
$requests = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM encashments WHERE status = ? ");
$requests->execute(array($stat));
$reqs = $requests->fetchColumn();
echo $reqs;
```

My html:

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="/user/admin/encashment/requests">Encashment Requests <div id="counter" style="color:red;"></div></a></li>
```

Everything is working fine, but I wonder why the div moves to the next line? Looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the number is below the `Encashment Requests` link and I want it just to be beside it. How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `#counter` `css` property `display` to `inline-block`

```css
#counter {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li role="presentation"><a href="/user/admin/encashment/requests">Encashment Requests <div id="counter" style="color:red;">3</div></a></li>
```